# How to add Glyphicons in Select option in bootstrap form?

Tags: html

I wanna add some birth-day cake glyphicon in bootstrap form 
like that

[image]

Comment: Review this https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 1):

Use this `<i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i>` within your input field.

Also refer to this to get more information about icons https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Comment: Can you give an example how to implement this is in birthday column? I tried but can't get wanted result